# How to get current System Timestamp for Firebase? in Android Kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase pagging and therefore i need current timestamp for queries database in firebase ? can anyone knows how to get current timestamp from system?

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("news")
        .orderBy("timestamp",Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        .startAfter(timestamp) // for here i need current system timestamp..?? how can i??
        .limit(4)
        .get()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`

If you want the date value of `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` you can use `.toDate()`.
See [FireStore Timesteamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp/).

If you want the current Date as a timestamp you can use the following

**For Firebase Functions**

```
import admin = require('firebase-admin');

const todayAsTimestamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()
```

**For local projects**

```
import { Timestamp } from '@google-cloud/firestore';

const myTimestampAsDate = Timestamp.now()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this led me in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

Ferin's answer led me in the right direction. This what worked for me in my current project using Kotlin when getting the timestamp value to store in firebase cloud firestore.

```
val createdAt = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

If anyone is confused I can explain further. Happy coding everyone!